# meaning of *( (int *)ptr+1)

Tags: c, pointers, casting, type-conversion

Suppose ptr is some pointer then :

```
*((int *)ptr+1)
```

means what:

first type cast ptr to int * then increment by one, then dereference.

OR

first increment ptr by one, then typecast, then dereference.

Comment: Check an [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cast has a higher precedence that addition, c.f. [here](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/c/c-precedence.html). Thus, first convert to integer pointer and then add `1*sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 4):

`ptr` is a pointer to anything. `(int *) ptr` is a pointer to int which points to the same place than `ptr`, but assumes the pointee to be `int`. `(int *)ptr + 1` points one cell (aka. one int) further in memory. `*((int *)ptr+1)` is that int.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the short version of `ptr[1]`, if ptr is an `int *` pointer of course.

so

> first type cast ptr to int * then increment by one, then dereference.

Answer (score 2):

The first proposition:
Cast ptr to int*, then increment by one and finally get the int at this address.

This is a way to handle structured data, when you only have, for example, a stream of char in input.

Answer (score 1):

```
*((int *)ptr+1)
```

**that means :**

- incress the pointer to next place in memory by(sizeof(ptr))
- then cast the pointer to pointer of integer.
- then get the first sizeof(int) bytes!

Answer (score 1):

This codes shows pretty much what you are doing:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( ) {

    int onetwo[] = { 1, 2};
    /*create a void pointer to one two*/
    void* ptr = (void*) onetwo;

    printf ( "pointer onetwo[0] = %p\n", &onetwo[0]  );
    printf ( "pointer onetwo[1] = %p\n", &onetwo[1]  );

    /* since you are doing pointer arithmetics
     * it's really important you cast ptr back to
     * int* otherwise the compiler might not
     * return a pointer to onetwo[1] but if sizeof(int)
     * is 4 bytes
     */
    printf ( "value = %d\n", *( (int*)ptr + 1) );

    /* in this print statement ptr is still a void* when
     * it is incremented, therefore it points between 
     * onetwo[0] and onetwo[1]
     */

    printf ( "value = %d\n", * ((int*)( ptr + 1)) );

    /*casting to int* is for illustration properties */
    printf ( "This points between onetwo[0] and onetwo[1] because it's at %p\n", (int*) (ptr + 1));


    return 0;

}
```

output on my machine yields :

```
~/programming/stackoverflow$ ./p
pointer onetwo[0] = 0x7fffdd8e2fc0
pointer onetwo[1] = 0x7fffdd8e2fc4
value = 2
value = 33554432
This points between onetwo[0] and onetwo[1] because it's at 0x7fffdd8e2fc1
```

I hope this demonstrates some of the effects of pointer arithmetics.